# Xpath search for .docx

Tags: apache, parsing, xpath, apache-poi, docx

I want to read specific text from the subtable present in .docx file.
Is there a efficient way like xpath traversing or similar api supported in java.

Currently i tried reading .docx using java apache poi (code snippet below),  but this way i have to iterate all the nodes based on tag 'w:tr'  and read the nodes text value.   Is there any approach to quickly retrieve required data based on searchpattern like xpath.?? . Any inputs is highly appreciated.

```
              File myFile = new File( "D:\\XLS-Pages\\TestSherwin.docx" );
              ZipFile docxFile = new ZipFile( myFile );
        ZipEntry documentXML = docxFile.getEntry( "word/document.xml" );
        InputStream documentXMLIS = docxFile.getInputStream( documentXML );
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse( documentXMLIS );

        org.w3c.dom.Element tElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList n = (NodeList) tElement.getElementsByTagName( "w:tr" );
```

Comment: Did you try following any of the many many Java XPath tutorials? If so, what problems did you hit when applying them to your file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath in docx4j; support is based on JAXB's support for XPath, with the various limitations which that entails.